# Volumio - Play specific track via REST API

Tags: raspberry-pi, volumio

Using the REST API -https://volumio.github.io/docs/API/REST_API.html

Is there a method to play a specific track?

eg .

```
volumio.local/api/v1/commands/?cmd=playplaylist&name=Rock
```

But use a track name instead of a playlist.